# Why isn't my JSON post method working on my JSON file in local web server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I just recently tried learning javascript and I want to make a website that uses JSON files as storage. So far I have been to make the GET method work:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'Projects/Sample/data.json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("I have friends!", data);
  }
});
```

Since I am learning from this site http://rest.learncode.academy/, I also tried using its post method:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'Projects/Sample/data.json',
  data: {name: 'Billy Bob', age: 27},
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Friend added!", data); //the new item is returned with an ID
  }
});
```

This code works if I use the website's json http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends. But when I try to use my JSON file located in my web server, new data don't seem to be added. I am using XAMPP as my web server.

Comment: What does the error console tell you about what goes wrong?

Comment: Where are you running the AJAX request? On your local server too (so it's a same origin request), or on a different server?

Comment: @Terry Inside the body of my html, on the html file in my local web server

Comment: You need server side code to store the file.

Comment: @Pekka웃 It doesn't have any error but it doesn't console log  {name: 'Billy Bob', age: 27}

Comment: @RolandStarke Can you elaborate on that? Keywords I code google or sample codes I can look at? Sorry I'm just really new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth looking at the accepted answer on this question:

[Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)

I'd definitely recommend the `lvh.me` option, so instead of

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'Projects/Sample/data.json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("I have friends!", data);
  }
});
```

You'd have

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://lvh.me/data.json',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("I have friends!", data);
  }
});
```

Assuming your `data.json` is in the base folder (i.e. you can access it by hitting http://lvh.me/data.json

Comment: It has an error that says XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lvh.me/SVmatches.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: @WannabeWeebDev Can you browse to that address and see the JSON file? If so it may be worth looking into the other options posted in the other Question, such as `--disable-web-security` flag for Chrome. But keep in mind you only want to use that flag while testing. Remove it as soon as you're done as it means your browser is insecure.

Comment: Yep, I can see the JSON using the lvh URL. I tried to look into that but never really understood where to actually do that in Chrome, I try to study it again hmmm.

Edit: nvm about the disable web security, just googled it bit lol I'm bad.

Comment: I was able to no longer see the XMLHttpRequest error by opening my site URL with a disabled wed security Chrome session using this: `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` 
but it still doesn't POST new data in the JSON file...

Comment: @WannabeWeebDev You never really would be adding data to your JSON file, in the case they're showing, they've an API likely writing into a database. JSON would really be you reading the data only.

Comment: Oh okay so does this mean I really can't use JSON files as an alternative from using databases like MySQL? Thanks a lot for the responses btw!

Comment: @WannabeWeebDev no problem at all, I mean, you could, but not something I'd recommend trying to implement. If you wanted to work from local file/database or whatever, I'd recommend maybe [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/onefile.html) , [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) . I personally used Pouch on a recent project and it worked wonders for me, very easy to implement too.